# What is the Azure Blob Upload Exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure

I know this is a basic question, but I can't seam to find a confirmation to this in [MSDN CloudBlobClient.Timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.cloudblobclient.timeout.aspx).

Now the question is simple, when the Timeout limit is exceeded does the CloudBlobClient fire a standard [TimeoutException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timeoutexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or something more specific to the CloudBlobClient?

Currently I am using simply TimeoutException, but I am staring to doubt myself, I would like to confirm that the exception is at least extended from the TimeoutException, but weirdly can't find anything in MSDN on the matter.

Comment: Reduce the TimeOut to force an exception.  Also catch a general exception so you will know if it was not TimeoutException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after running a simple test I found out, if the Timeout is too low, then the TimeoutException will not be thrown (somehow not suprising) but the [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.StorageServerException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.storageserverexception_members.aspx). With the `ErrorCode` set to `StorageErrorCode.ServiceTimeout` is thrown instead.